# Interaction between jQuery validate plugin and form field events

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validate plugin to validate a form. In addition, on blur of one of the input fields I want to execute a function that modifies another form element (a select list), but only if the input field is valid.

So my jquery code is something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   $("#form_name").validate(
     {rules: 
        {
         input_field_name: {remote: validation_url}
        ,input_field_name2: {remote: validation_url2}
        }
     ,messages:
        {
         input_field_name: {remote: jQuery.format("Error message")}
        ,input_field_name2: {remote: jQuery.format("Different error message")}
        }
     });
   $("#input_field_name").blur(function()
     {
       if ($("#input_field_name").valid())
         {$.ajax({dataType: "json"
                      ,url: "url_to_get_new_select_list_options"
                     ,data: {input_field_name : $("#input_field_name").val()}
                  ,success: function(data)
                                {
                                 $select_options = $("#example_select_list");
                                 $select_options.empty();
                                 $.each(data.tp, function(key, val)
                                         {$select_options.append('<option id="'+val.id+'">'+val.desc+'</option>')}
                                       )
                                }
                })
          }
     });
  });
```

And my html is something like:

```
<form name="form_name" id="form_name" method="post" action="url_to_process_form">
<select name="example_select_list" id="example_select_list">
<option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="11111">One</option>
<option value="22222">Two</option>
<option value="33333">Three</option>
<option value="44444">Four</option>
<option value="55555">Five</option>
</select>

<input id="input_field_name" type="text" size=10 maxlength=20 name="input_field_name2">
<input id="input_field_name2" type="text" size=10 maxlength=20 name="input_field_name2">   

</form>
```

As far as I can tell the problem is that the blur function is being executed before validate at which time .*valid* returns false, so my blur function is doing nothing useful. If I blur the field again (without modifying its value), .*valid* then returns true and my select list gets updated as required.

But I can't figure out how to validate the form (or just that specific input field) so .*valid* returns true on first pass through the blur function.

Sorry for such a newb question.

Comment: So why not show your HTML too?

Comment: The plugin already validates "on focus out" by default.  Why exactly are you trying to implement a `blur` handler on top of this?

Comment: Thanks Sparky. I have other validation rules but left them out of my sample code for brevity. I've added them and sample html to clarify. I only want the function to execute on blur of that one field and only if that one field's value is valid. This is because there is a dependency between the input field and select list values - if the input field value changes (and is valid), the select list has to update accordingly,then be reselected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved this problem myself, and will record the solution here for posterity.

I originally thought there was an issue with queueing the validate and on blur functions and was trying to solve that. I finally discovered that the problem is that there is a slight lag in the remote ajax call in validate - the ajax response has not yet arrived when I am checking whether the form field is valid.

I solved this using setInterval as follows:

```
$("#input_field_name").blur(function()
    {
     var intrvl = window.setInterval(checkPendingRequest,1000);
     function checkPendingRequest() 
         {
          if ($.active < 1)  //Checks if there are any open Ajax requests
              {
               if ($("#input_field_name").valid())
                   {$.ajax({dataType: "json"
                                ,url: "url_to_get_new_select_list_options"
                               ,data: {input_field_name : $("#input_field_name").val()}
                            ,success: function(data)
                                {
                                 $select_options = $("#example_select_list");
                                 $select_options.empty();
                                 $.each(data.tp, function(key, val)
                                     {$select_options.append('<option id="'+val.id+'">'+val.desc+'</option>')}
                                 )
                                }
                          })
                    window.clearInterval(intrvl);
                   }
              }
         }
    }
)
```

I hope that helps someone else one day.